# SMS usage with the mobile app

Tags: android, mobile, mobile-application

Is it possible and relevan for me to do this process?

- User A: Use smartphone
- User B: Use the old type of phone (ex nokia 103, samsung GT-E1200T)

  1. User A request a booking through mobile app
  2. Then, SMS is delivered to every user B
  3. User B reply through SMS
  4. Available users B will be listed in the mobile app used by the user A. If User B reject the request, the non-available users B will not be listed in the mobile app used by the user A
  5. Users A can choose any one of the available users B
  6. SMS will be delivered to user B that has been chosen

Is it possible to interact both mobile app and the usage of SMS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is possible. I created an app some how similar to that. You will need to have:

1) sqlite database to store your lists. Check this [example](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html)

2) Send SMS: check this [example](http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/06/send-sms-in-android-example.html#.U-3HcVZwaUk)

3) SMS Broadcast Receiver. check this example: [Incomming SMS Broadcast Receiver](http://androidexample.com/Incomming_SMS_Broadcast_Receiver_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=62&aaid=87)

check them and let me know if you still need help.

Comment: Currently, this is the plan for my project. Seems it is possible, I feel so glad to start the research and work. Thanks for the info. And I'll be surely to ask you again. Thank you very much!

Comment: hello sir. i would like to ask, to enable the process above, is it using sms gateway function at the database server? @Karim

Comment: no sms gateway is used. the sms are sent from the phone. In my case the user uploads a list to a MySQL server (thr a website but not essential), the app on phone pulls the data from server and sends the sms. The results (Del reports and replies) are uploaded back to server for tracking purpose.

Comment: In order to enable the data pulling from the server, I need to make the server online rite? Instead of making my own server in the pc, is there any solution? If i'm not mistaken.. Mind to correct me, please.. tq @Karim

Comment: yes you need an online server accessible thr internet so that your phone can see it. having a MySQL server on your computer won't work. What will happen is that you send your data in JSON format over the internet. 2) you need webservice (in my case written in PHP) on an online server to receive the data and save it to MySQL database. you can email me more info about the structure of your app or what you want to achieve and I will give you a better advice

Comment: may i know your email so that i can reach you? @Karim

Comment: @Kreng Kongkeng its: karimnower@gmail.com. its on my profile.

Comment: owh.. ok sir.. anything i'll just email you.. tq very much sir :) @Karim